# How to resize iframe chat by drag it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have some code to create iframe and connect jquery scripts here:

```
(function($){ 
    var client_id = '1',
        p= 'right',
        vp = 'bottom';
        h = '550',
        dw = '400';
    var d=document;
    var w=window;

    function l(){

        var s = document.createElement('div');
        s.id = 'chatrix_init_widget'; 
        s.style = 'position: fixed; z-index:101010; '+p+': 0; '+vp+': 0; height:'+h+'px; width: '+dw+'px';
        var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);

        var i = document.createElement('iframe');
        i.className = 'chatrix_iframe_container';
        i.height = '100%';
        i.width = '100%';
        i.src = '//danialart.biz/chatrix/widget.php?c='+client_id;
        var ss = document.getElementById('chatrix_init_widget').appendChild(i);

    }
    function s() {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        s.src = '//danialart.biz/chatrix/js/client_side.js';
        var ss = document.getElementById('chatrix_init_widget').parentNode.insertBefore(s, document.getElementById('chatrix_init_widget').nextSibling);
    }

    if(d.readyState=='complete'){
        l();
        s();
    }else{
        if(w.attachEvent){
            w.attachEvent('onload',function(){
            l();
            s();
        });
    }else{
        w.addEventListener('load',function(){l();s();},false);
    }}})(jQuery);
```

And when page is ready i want to connect jquery resizable to my div with id chatrix_init_widget by clicking in top of this div (example on jivosite.com). But its doesnt work becaue when i click somewhere in this div - iframe catch my click and think i'm clicking in outer website. How can i fix that and do like on example to resize my chat iframe box ?

Comment: no matter, i connect jquery and jquery ui resizable, but its not work because to resize i need to click - and click everywhere on this area not work. Any click function not work too on this div id, when i call it on client_side.js, so problem not int resize script.

Comment: I said I cant see your code where you try to apply the plugin.. Can you add that in the question